# Proving that two branch cuts can cancel out

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, laurent-series, branch-cuts

Define the following functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}:$ $$u(z)=\frac{\log \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{z}\quad \left[-\pi\leqslant\arg \left(z+\tfrac12\right)<\pi\right];\quad v(z)=\frac{\log z}{z}\quad \left[-\pi\leqslant\arg z<\pi\right]$$
The function $f=u-v$ is holomorphic on $1<|z|<R$ for any $R>1$. The way I picture this is that the arguments essentially "cancel out" when we cross $(-\infty,-1)$, which lies within the intersection of the branch cuts $(-\infty,0]$ and $(-\infty,-\frac12]$:

[image]

- How would I argue this *formally* though? If write it out we have: $$\frac{1}{z}\log\left|1+\frac{1}{2z}\right|+\frac{1}{z}\left(\arg \left(z+\frac12\right)-\arg z\right)$$
  But I can't see exactly why the arguments cancel?

I am asked to find the first terms of the Laurent expansion about $0$ in an annulus as above, and deduce the integral of $f$ around a circle of radius $1<r<R$ centered at $0$. I get:
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2z}\right)=\frac{1}{2z}\left(\frac{1}{2z}-\frac{1}{8z^2}+\frac{1}{24z^3}-\cdots\right)$$
which vanishes? The way the question is worded makes me think I should be getting something more interesting than just $0$, have I gone wrong?

Comment: write that when $Re(z) > 0$ : $u(z e^{2i\pi}) = u(z)+ \frac{2 i \pi}{z}$, and that $v(ze^{2i \pi}) = v(z) + \frac{2 i \pi}{z}$

Comment: by analytic continuation, this stays true for every $z$ that is accessible  from the right plane (without traversing the branch cuts) hence the two branch cuts on the left cancel (leaving only a branch cut on $(-1/2,0)$)

Comment: (the notation $u(ze^{2i \pi})$ meaning literally : rotating around the branch point, following the function by analytic continuation, i.e. [walking on the Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm) where the branch point is an isolated singularity)

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry I don't quite understand the first comment?

Comment: what don't you understand ? when you rotate around the branch point of $\log z$ at $z=0$ you get the equation : $\log (z e^{it}) = \log (z) + i t$ for $t$ real and "small enough", and hence  $\log (z e^{2i\pi}) = \log (z) + 2i \pi$ (of course $z e^{2 i \pi} = z$ so this is a special notation for branch points...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $u$ and $v$ are not defined at $-\frac 12$ and $0$ respectively so you can't pretend they are functions $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$.

From the properties of the principal branch of $\log$, $u$ and $v$ are holomorphic on $U = \Bbb C \setminus \Bbb R_{\le 0}$.
Their difference $u-v$ is also holomorphic on $U$.

Next, $\log(1+\frac 1{2z})$ is holomorphic on $V = \Bbb C \setminus [-\frac 12 ; 0]$.

Since $U \subset V$, we have a holomorphic function $h$ defined on $U$ by 
$h(z) = \log(z+\frac 12) - \log(z) - \log(1+\frac 1{2z}) \in 2ik\pi\Bbb Z$.
Since $U$ is connected and $\Bbb Z$ is discrete, $h$ has to be constant on $U$. Looking at what happens at $z=1$ we have $h(1) = \log \frac 32 - \log 1 - \log \frac 32 = 0$, and so $h(z) = 0$ forall $z \in U$.

This shows that $\log(z+\frac 12) - \log(z)$, even though we only know (from its expression) that it is holomorphic on $U$, it coincides on $U$ with $\log(1+\frac 1{2z})$, which is holomorphic on $V$.
Since the values of $\log(z+\frac 12) - \log(z)$ on $(-\infty ; -2)$ are the limit of the values of the expression when you approach the real axis from below, they also coincide with $\log(1+\frac 1{2z})$ on $(-\infty ; -2)$ because it is continuous there.

And so $ \forall z \in V, u(z)-v(z) = \frac 1z \log(1 + \frac 1{2z})$, which is holomorphic on $V$ .

Letting $w = \frac 1z$, we have $u(z)-v(z) = w\log(1+w/2)$, whose power series at $w=0$ has radius of convergence $2$ : $w\log(1+w/2) = w^2/2 - w^3/8 + w^4/24 - w^5/64 \dots$. The coefficient of $z^{-1} = w$ is $0$ so your integral is $0$.

---

Another way to see that the integral is $0$ is to compare the integrals of $u$ and $v$ on a large circle.

Since (as $|z| \to \infty$), $\log(z+\frac 12) = \log(z) + O(1/|z|)$, you have $u(z) = v(z) + O(1/|z|^2)$. And so the difference of their integral on a circle of radius $R$ is a $O(1/R)$. Since it doesn't depend on $R$, this difference has to be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the power series for the difference:
$$
\begin{align}
u-v
&=\frac{\log\left(z+\frac12\right)}z-\frac{\log(z)}z\\
&=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1{2z}\right)}z\\
&=\frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{8z^3}+\frac1{24z^4}-\frac1{64z^5}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n2^nz^{n+1}}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
This series converges for $\left|z\right|\gt\frac12$ and has $0$ residue (the coefficient of the $\frac1z$ term is $0$).

Two branches may differ by a constant, so if we evaluate at $z=1$, we get that the difference of these functions is
$$
\log\left(\frac32\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n2^n}
$$
which agrees with the formula above.

Comment: the branch cuts could be moved, and it would not be true anymore that the branch cuts cancel, so you have to justify that this is indeed the (Laurent) series for the difference of the two functions.

Comment: If we evaluate the functions at $z=1$, we get equality. The only difference that the various branches will have is a constant.  I have edited my answer to mention this.

Comment: still don't get your argument. what if the branch cuts were on $(0,e^{2i \pi / 3} \infty)$ and $(-1/2,-1/2+e^{-2i \pi / 3} \infty)$ ??

Comment: Except along the branch cuts, the functions are analytic; therefore, their difference $$ \frac{\log\left(1+\frac1{2z}\right)}z $$ is analytic in the same region. That function is analytic over the region $\left|z\right|\gt\frac12$, and so the branch cuts in that region cancel.